# Join 2 CSV with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 CSV (emails1.csv and emails2.csv)

What i need is Join these 2 CSV into one, because they are too big for work with excel.

I need to export to CSV and TXT.

What i did is create a Python file:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv("emails1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("emails2.csv")

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["email"])
df3.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)
```

The CSV only have the email column

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, you just want to load and concat the email column from both CSVs, and don't care about the other columns?

Comment: Sorry, is not concat, is pd.merge

Comment: In that case can you provide some sample input and expected output? It's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: the output like this: 

email1
email1
email1
email2
email2
email2

but to the column... i dont know how to explain.

Comment: i think you are getting merged final csv ,you only want to have email column  in the merged csv right

Comment: @jvera No, that's not what I asked. I want you to take 5 rows from your CSVs, along with your _expected output_, and _add it to your question_ using the edit link. If you can do that, then it becomes possible to help you.

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: i cant edit the question :(

Comment: Of course you can... Click the "edit" link at the bottom, of your Q.

Comment: Ok, from the website dont show the edit button, but from the app i can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing out on **how** to join the two `dataframes`.
I just made a small adjustment to your given code and it works perfectly.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv("emails1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("emails2.csv")

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=["email"], how='outer')
df3.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)
```

Please note the `how` parameter, and the way `merge` is called.

This is `emails1.csv` :

```
email
one@gmail.com
two@gmail.com
```

This is `emails2.csv` :

```
email
three@gmail.com
four@gmail.com
```

And this is the `final.csv` after executing my code:

```
email
one@gmail.com
two@gmail.com
three@gmail.com
four@gmail.com
```

I hope this is what you wanted.
:-) cheers!

Comment: Thanks!, your code work, but i was searching more and i found a variation of your code:

This is Your code:
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=["email"], how='outer')
df3.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)

This is the Variation:
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["email"], how='outer')
df3.to_csv("final.csv",index=False)

Both works, but, why you are using the df1.merge? what is the different? also, how did you avoid the email from emails2? because skip the name of the column.

Thanks!!

Comment: Regarding skipping the name of column, it is one of the cool little tricks pandas does on itself. Whenever you load a csv file into pandas dataframe, it automatically takes the first row to be the row of column headers and the rows below it the actual data. If you find it inconvenient, i guess you can avoid it by passing a certain parameter while reading, i guess "header=False", if i remember correctly.

Comment: And about the way "merge" was called... Well, turns out we both learnt something new today. Definitely pd.merge works too! Infact, it is more "accepted". I have been using df.merge up until now, which is why i pointed that out.
Thanks. :D

Comment: Thanks! great explanation! 

Another thing, how can i do for join several file? i mean, that work only for 2 files, but what about if i have more files?

Comment: Have a look at the pandas "concat" docs. This just solves everything.